# How to open Excel object from a relative path?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open an Excel workbook from a Windows batch file. I have used the following line of code which does the job but I want it to use a relative path.

```
Set xlBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ashg\CSVtoxlsx.xlsm", 0, False)
```

How do I construct the relative path and the Excel file name together to open the Excel file?

Comment: Path relevant to what? show where the script would be and where the excel file would be?

Comment: Both files (.xlsm and batch) on the same path. C:\Users\ashg

Comment: So then remove the path?

Comment: It didn't work for me. I tried: Set xlBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("CSVtoxlsx.xlsm", 0, False)

Comment: did you receive an error?

Comment: Yeah it says, sorry, we couldn't find CSVtoxlsx.xlsm

Comment: Then the file is not in the same directory or you are running it as admin? How do you run the vba script?

Comment: Files are in the same directory. I'm sure I'm running as an admin. I have a .vbs file saved in the directory. So by double-clicking it. It works fine when I mention the full path. I tried running cmd as admin and running the script from CLI. The problem is still there

Comment: ok, but that is a problem because cmd admin starts in `c:\windows\system32` and double clicking it would probably also start it from the vba executable path.

Comment: you can determine the directory the script runs as working directory. `Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") Debug.Print wshell.CurrentDirectory`